# Convert MS Access Color to hex with php?

Tags: php, ms-access

i have a MS Access Color like "16777215". This is the color white (#ffffff). How can i convert this color string to hex like #ffffff with php?

greetings!

Comment: The Answer is dechex(); http://php.net/manual/de/function.dechex.php

Answer (score 2):

There is a complete function which converts MS Access color values to RGB HEX. Thanks to WojtekT and poldixd for a few tips to solve this.

```
<?php
function color_msaccess2hex($in) {
    $hex = str_pad(dechex($in), 6, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

    // Switch first and third byte
    $hex = mb_substr($hex,4,2).mb_substr($hex,2,2).mb_substr($hex,0,2);

    return '#'.$hex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Color values in MS Access are not stored in RGB mode but something like BGR.
That means that after converting the value to hex You need to switch places of first and third byte. Example:

Access color code: `5275647`, converted to hex is: `507FFF`, after switching first and third byte you get: `FF7F50`, and that's your html color code.

Here is a conversion table so you see what i mean:
http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm

Comment: This works for me:


`return str_pad(dechex($in), 6, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: This doesn't return correct html color code. This works on 16777215 because it is byte symetrical, but it wouldn't work on other values.